# Преобразовать один HashMap в другой по заданному алгоритму с помощью Java StreamAPI

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, java-hashmap

Мне необходимо составить статистику появления ошибки(ERROR) в файле логов за минуту и за час. Мне удалось составить статистику по минутам используя `Map<String,Long>`, которая выглядит так: `{11:05=3, 11:20=2, 17:21=4, 21:12=1}` т.е. в 11 часов 05 минут произошли три ошибки, в 11 часов 20 минут произошло две ошибки и т.д., как видно это минутная статистика.

Теперь мне необходимо составить часовую статистику следующим образом - нужно все строковые ключи сократить до двух первых символов т.е. получить часы 
(было 11:05=3 - стало 11=3) и если такой ключ уже есть нужно его значение добавить к новому значению, в результате получить {11=5, 17=4, 21=1} т.к. в 11 часов произошло в сумме 5 ошибок

```
    public void hourStatistics(Map<String,Long> minuteMap) {

        Map<String,Long> hourStatistics = new HashMap<>();
        minuteMap.forEach((s, Long) -> {
        ???
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
minuteMap.forEach((timeWithMinutes, counter) -> {
    hourStatistics.merge(timeWithMinutes.substring(0, 2), counter, Long::sum);
});
```

Comment: спасибо, подошло!